# How to prevent objects from colliding into each other in the Unity editor?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, map-editor

I am building a map for a game... I am making most of the buildings with cubes. When I move a cube next to another one they go through each other... Which creates flickering. This is making it very hard to build the map. How do I enable collisions in the editor (Make it so they don't go through each other when you try to move one)?

Here is a picture:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> **Surface snapping**
>
> While dragging in the center using the Move tool, hold Shift and Control (Command on Mac) to quickly snap the GameObject to the intersection of any Collider.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html

Vertex snapping, also mentioned in that manual page, is often useful as well.

By the way, the flickering you describe is known as "[Z-fighting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)"